# Is there an SQL for XML?

Tags: php, sql, xml

Is there an XML language that works like SQL where you pass variables and it retrieves/updates values based on that?

I would like to pass args to a file and retrieve/update values in the files based on my args.

I am more inclined to use PHP to export the XML file. Currently I can export as a XML-DOM but I would like to know if there is any XML format that works as per my requirement.

Comment: Are you asking for XSLT and/or XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely:

- XPath is extremely useful for selecting parts of an XML document.
- XQuery is built on XPath and is like an SQL for XML.
- XSLT is built on XPath and supports transformations between XML documents.

Comment: That helps. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Consider XSLT which is similar to SQL in many ways:

- Special-purpose and declarative type language;
- Integrates with application layer such as Java, PHP, Python, etc. using various modules or libraries like PHP's PDO;
- Manipulates both structure and data not unlike SQL's DDL and DML;
- Ability to pass parameters from application layer such as PHP's [`setParameter`](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php):

  ```
  $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
  $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

  $proc->setParameter('', 'xslt_param_name', $php_variable);
  ```
- Adheres to standards (e.g., [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/)) similar to SQL ANSI to allow for portability

Comment: That helps. Awesome